# Do all of the orbits have the same dimensions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and let $X$ be a $G$-variety. [It's stated in the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.4299.pdf)  (pg. 13) that all orbits are closed and have the same dimensions if the graph
$$\Gamma_{X}:=\{(g x, x) \mid g \in G, x \in X\}=\bigcup_{x \in X} G x \times G x \subset X \times X$$
is closed. They say that the statement about the dimensions is true because
$$G x \times\{x\}=p_{2}^{-1}(x) \text { where } p_{2}: \Gamma_{X} \rightarrow X \text { is the second projection. }$$

But I don't understand this reasoning. Can someone explain it to me, please?

Comment: Also on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/383962